# how to get parent id data from grandchild id data

Tags: javascript

I have the people data below. where in people data there is "dataInduk" and inside "dataInduk" there is "dataAnak". how can I find people id data if I have "idAnak". this is my code

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "James",
    id: 1,
    dataInduk: [
      {
        idInduk: "1a",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "1a1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "1a2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        idInduk: "1b",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "1b1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "1b2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    id: 2,
    dataInduk: [
      {
        idInduk: "2a",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "2a1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "2a2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        idInduk: "2b",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "2b1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "2b2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

for example:
when i find from idAnak = '2b2' then show id "2" from people

Comment: the data is just 3 layer deep right? Can different `idInduk` or `people` have the same `idAnak`?

Comment: @kennarddh Yes, all the id are different

Comment: @Quinn: Did any answer work for you? If yes, accept and/or upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the person by iterating `dataInduk` and iterate `dataAnak` in every `dataInduk` to check if `dataInduk` includes `idAnak`

```js
const IDAnakToIDPeople = idAnak => {
  const person = people.find(personIter =>
    personIter.dataInduk.some(dataInduk =>
      dataInduk.dataAnak.some(dataAnak => dataAnak.idAnak === idAnak),
    ),
  )

  return person.id
}

// Test cases (actual, expected)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("1a1"), 1)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("1a2"), 1)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("1b1"), 1)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("1b2"), 1)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("2a1"), 2)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("2a2"), 2)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("2b1"), 2)
console.log(IDAnakToIDPeople("2b2"), 2)
```

```html
<script>
const people = [
  {
    name: "James",
    id: 1,
    dataInduk: [
      {
        idInduk: "1a",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "1a1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "1a2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        idInduk: "1b",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "1b1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "1b2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    id: 2,
    dataInduk: [
      {
        idInduk: "2a",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "2a1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "2a2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        idInduk: "2b",
        dataAnak: [
          {
            idAnak: "2b1",
          },
          {
            idAnak: "2b2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
</script>
```

#### References

- [Array Some MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array Find MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: How is this any different from an answer already posted?

Comment: Return only 1 id because `idAnak` is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```js
const people=[{name:"James",id:1,dataInduk:[{idInduk:"1a",dataAnak:[{idAnak:"1a1"},{idAnak:"1a2"}]},{idInduk:"1b",dataAnak:[{idAnak:"1b1"},{idAnak:"1b2"}]}]},{name:"John",id:2,dataInduk:[{idInduk:"2a",dataAnak:[{idAnak:"2a1"},{idAnak:"2a2"}]},{idInduk:"2b",dataAnak:[{idAnak:"2b1"},{idAnak:"2b2"}]}]}];

console.log(
   people.filter(e => 
      e.dataInduk.some(j => j.dataAnak.some(k => k.idAnak === '2b2')))
         ?.map(i => i.id)
);
```